# CakePHP 3 - CSV exporter according to user inputs

Tags: html, csv, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi i'm working with a CSV exporter and it works pretty well for me. All credits to this guy (https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview) who did an amazing job at this.

So by default if i want to get some records displayed on a table to a csv view i just have to do the following.

**Customers Controller**

```
public function export() {
    $this->response->download('export.csv');
    $opts1['order'] = array('Customers.name' => 'asc');
    $data = $this->Customers->find('all',$opts1)->toArray();

    $_serialize = 'data';
    $_extract = ['id', 'name' ,'nic' , 'dob' , 'address'];

    $_header = ['ID', 'Name' ,'NIC' , 'DOB' , 'Address'];
    $this->set(compact('data', '_serialize', '_header', '_extract'));

    $this->viewBuilder()->className('CsvView.csv');
    return;
}
```

**View**

```
<?= $this->Html->link('Report', [
        'controller' => 'customers', 
        'action' => 'export',
        '_ext' => 'csv'
        ],

        ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) 
      ?>
```

I'm trying to get the CSV file to display the data according to the user selected dates from the frontend (from a html5 calendar view). How can I achive this? What is the approach to send data from the frontend to the controller in order to get a filtered output?

**HTML5 date picker**

I'm currently using the CakePHP v3.4.7.

PS - I'm really new to this :S trying to get familiar with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create one form with any unique id.
2. Keep your datepicker inside that form.
3. Add a Link or button.
4. When you click on Link/button, call AJAX. Get the form data and pass it to your controller function which contains the code for generating CSV.
5. Store the CSV in you assets folder.
6. You function must return the name of CSV file.
7. Now on your success AJAX call add below line
   location.href="path/to/csv_file_in_asset".